# File exists, cant be read giving path in standard way, identical strings don't match - Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I have a very frustrating problem reading files in Groovy (windows). I've spent quite a bit of time trying to track down the root cause. However I have boiled it down to two identical file names not matching, so i'm bamboozled!

Here's some diagnostic code and the results:

```
def rootPath = "x:/"
def filePath

files.each
{

    filePath = rootPath + it
    File xmlFile = new File(filePath)
    println xmlFile.canRead()    //returns : false
    println xmlFile.exists()     //returns : false

    xmlFile = new File(new File(filePath).getParent() + "/" + new File(filePath).getName().toString())
    println xmlFile.canRead()     //returns : false


    String fileName = new File(filePath).getName()
    String parentDir = new File(filePath).getParent()
    new File(parentDir).list().each
    {
        println "|" + it + "|" + fileName + "|"
               //returns |PreUpload_140111-192158.xml|PreUpload_140111-192158.xml|

        println it.toString().equals(fileName)
               //returns false!!

        println "Can Read : " + new File(parentDir + "/" + it.toString()).canRead()
               //returns true
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `files` that you use for `each` on line 4?

Comment: `files` is a list of partial path strings such as : `Rel_2011.01/V112V80V90V100Mk8/2011.01.259/PC_12_V112_3MW_50HZ_Target_20110114-122312/PreUpload_140111-120351.xml`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you get the same results with this cleaned up code?

```
def rootPath = "x:/"

files.each { f ->
  File xmlFile = new File( rootPath, f )
  String filename = xmlFile.name
  File parentDir = xmlFile.parent

  parentDir.list().each { f2 ->
    // Does this still print |PreUpload_140111-192158.xml|PreUpload_140111-192158.xml|
    println "|$f2|$fileName|"

    // Does this still print false?
    println( f2 == fileName )

    boolean canRead = new File( parentDir, f2 ).canRead()

    // still prints true ?
    println "Can Read : $canRead"
  }
}
```

---

**[Edit]**

So, it would appear that the issue was `CR` characters at the end of the Strings in the `files` collection

Not sure how the variable `files` is populated, but something somewhere needs a `trim()` ;-)

Comment: // Does this still print |PreUpload_140111-   192158.xml|PreUpload_140111-192158.xml|  
`println "|$f2|$fileName|"  `
//Yes  
  
// Does this still print false?  
`println( f2 == fileName )  `
//Yes  
  
// still prints true ?  
`println "Can Read : $canRead"  `
//Yes

Comment: The code is intentionally "unclean" to be as explicit as possible. The code is just to demonstrate the problem. I don't actually want to read all the files in the files parent directory, just wanted to show that in a very round-about way the file actually can be read. I just want to read each of the files in "files".

Thanks for your help tho!

//Also : 
`println xmlFile.canRead()`

// Still is false

Comment: what does `println "$f2.class.name $fileName.class.name"` get you?  Also, there's a SPACE in your first comment `|PreUpload_140111- 192158.xml|PreUpload_140111-192158.xml|` is this by accident?  If not, I think we have our answer...

Comment: Yes, that was an accident. That gets me `java.lang.String java.lang.String`

Comment: Odd... can you try: `[ f2.split('')[1..-1], fileName.split('')[1..-1] ].transpose().each { a, b -> println "$a == $b ? ${ a == b }" }` to do a char by char comparison?

Comment: `P == P ? true
r == r ? true
e == e ? true
U == U ? true
p == p ? true
l == l ? true
o == o ? true
a == a ? true
d == d ? true
_ == _ ? true
1 == 1 ? true
4 == 4 ? true
0 == 0 ? true
1 == 1 ? true
1 == 1 ? true
1 == 1 ? true
- == - ? true
1 == 1 ? true
9 == 9 ? true
2 == 2 ? true
1 == 1 ? true
5 == 5 ? true
8 == 8 ? true
. == . ? true
x == x ? true
m == m ? true
l == l ? true`

Comment: And they are the same length : `println "${f2.length()} ${fileName.length()}"`? If so, I'm completely stumped :-(

Comment: Ahh haa! I've tried comparing the chars before but not the lengths. `27 28` !! Where/what can this mystery character be!!??

Comment: something like: `f2.split( '' )[1..-1].each { ch -> println "$ch(${(int)(ch[0] as char)})" }` might help?

Comment: `char mystery = filename.toCharArray()[filename.length()-1]    
println ">" + Character.digit(mystery,16) + "<"  //returns >-1<`

Comment: So `Character.digit` is telling us it's an invalid char? http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#digit%28char,%20int%29

Comment: `
filename.split( '' )[1..-1].each { ch -> println "$ch(${(int)(ch[0] as char)})" }   //returns : 
P(80)
r(114)
e(101)
U(85)
p(112)
l(108)
o(111)
a(97)
d(100)
_(95)
1(49)
4(52)
0(48)
1(49)
1(49)
1(49)
-(45)
1(49)
9(57)
2(50)
1(49)
5(53)
8(56)
.(46)
x(120)
m(109)
l(108)

(13)
`

Comment: Filename has a CR at the end of it.  However you are generating the `files` variable, it needs cleaning up

Comment: `File xmlFile = new File(rootPath,f.substring(0,f.length()-1))
println xmlFile.canRead()  //returns true!`
Thanks alot for your help! If you enter something like that as a new answer, I'll give you a tick so you get full credit!

Comment: Cool!  Thanks :-)  I think you need to look into the code which populates the `files` variable, and maybe add a `trim()` to get rid of the unwanted `CR` :-)  Glad we got to the bottom of it & good luck!